# Create Flat Record From Multiple Results (TSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have obtained my results from a query from joining various tables and the results I have returned are what I expect. What I need help is returning the results so that where a single record (reference) that has multiple lines of records, is converted into a one line (flat file) of results e.g. the attached image:

(Sorry for the bad table, not sure how to display it in a friendly format for this forum)

```
USER_ID RECEIPT_ID  ITEM_DES
----------------------------
  1        111        abc
  1        111        def
  1        111        ghi
  2        222        jkl
  2        222        mno
  3        333        pqr
```

So that it then looks like this:

```
USER_ID RECEIPT_ID  ITEM_DES    ITEM_DES1   ITEM_DES2
-----------------------------------------------------    
    1      111        abc          def         ghi
    2      222        jkl          jkl         NULL
    3      333        pqr          NULL        NULL
```

Is this possible? (sorry if this is a very simple query)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
;with cte as
(select *, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by receipt_id) rn
 from tbl)

select 
c1.user_id, 
c1.receipt_id, 
c1.item_des item_des, 
c2.item_des item_des2, 
c3.item_des item_des3 
from 
cte c1
left join cte c2 on c1.user_id = c2.user_id and c2.rn = 2
left join cte c3 on c1.user_id = c3.user_id and c3.rn = 3
where c1.rn = 1
```

This will work for a maximum of 3 distinct values of `item_des` for a given `user_id`. However, if you actually have, say, 10 distinct values, then you would have to join the CTE to itself 9 times. This quickly gets out of hand, and so I would not recommend this solution.

An alternative would be to use `PIVOT`. This would be done something like this:

```
;with cte as
(select *, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by receipt_id) rn
 from tbl)

select 
user_id, 
receipt_id, 
[1] as item_des,
[2] as item_des1,
[3] as item_des2 from
(select * from cte c1) s
pivot
(max(item_des)
 for rn in ([1],[2],[3])) p
```

We use the derived row number column to pivot the data. This is cleaner than the first because you avoid multiple joins. Again, we are constrained somewhat by the different possible values of row number. However, you could use dynamic SQL to generate that list and then use `PIVOT` as shown above.

Comment: Thank you @shree.pat18 I will see what I can do with the above.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('test1', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE test1;

CREATE TABLE test1 (
  USER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  RECEIPT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ITEM_DES VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test1 (USER_ID, RECEIPT_ID, ITEM_DES)
VALUES 
  (  1, 111,  'abc'),
  (  1, 111, 'def' ),
  (  1, 111, 'ghi' ),
  (  1, 111, 'fff' ),
  (  1, 111, 'sdf' ),
  (  2, 222, 'jkl' ),
  (  2, 222, 'mno' ),
  (  3, 333, 'pqr' );

SELECT USER_ID, RECEIPT_ID, ITEM_DES
FROM test1;

DECLARE @maxLevel TINYINT;
DECLARE @i TINYINT = 0;
DECLARE @sqlStatement VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

select @maxLevel = (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*)
from test1
GROUP BY USER_ID, RECEIPT_ID
);

PRINT @maxLevel;

WHILE @i < @maxLevel
BEGIN
SET @i = @i + 1;
SET @sqlStatement = @sqlStatement + '       [' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR) + CASE WHEN @i < @maxLevel THEN '],' ELSE ']' END + CHAR(13)
END

SET @sqlStatement = 'WITH cte'                                            + CHAR(13) +
                    'AS ('                                                + CHAR(13) +
                    '   SELECT *'                                         + CHAR(13) +
                    '       ,row_number() OVER ('                         + CHAR(13) +
                    '           PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY receipt_id' + CHAR(13) +
                    '           ) RN'                                     + CHAR(13) +
                    '   FROM test1'                                       + CHAR(13) +
                    '   )'                                                + CHAR(13) +
                    'SELECT USER_ID, RECEIPT_ID, '                        + CHAR(13) +
                    @sqlStatement +
                    'FROM cte'                                          + CHAR(13) +
                    'PIVOT (MAX(ITEM_DES) FOR RN IN (' + @sqlStatement + ') ) AS piv';

PRINT @sqlStatement;

EXECUTE (@sqlStatement);

IF OBJECT_ID('test1', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE test1;
```

Comment: Thanks Konstantin, I'll have a play with that and see if I can apply to my actual table (obvioulsy for data protection I couldnt actually post the information on there).